# What's the proper response to WM_ENDSESSION with ENDSESSION_CLOSEAPP and wParam == FALSE?

Tags: session, winapi, message

According to the [WM_ENDESSION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376889%28VS.85%29.aspx) docs, when lParam is ENDSESSION_CLOSEAPP and wParam is FALSE, *"the application should **not** shut down".*

- So, should I just ignore that and use the default response?
- What is it's purpose?

(I'm listening to Windows events/messages in Qt (C++) to shutdown some launched processes, but that's just the context and shouldn't have any bearing here...)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, a `WM_ENDSESSION` with `wParam==false` is simply for information. Prior to receiving this, your application will have received a `WM_QUERYENDSESSION`. If you did something to get ready to shut down in response to the `WM_QUERYENDSESSION`, you can un-do it when/if you received a `WM_ENDSESSION` with `wParam=false`. If you haven't taken any steps to start shutting down, you can just return 0.